# Find longest possible sequence for jumps

Tags: c#, algorithm, numbers, sequence

I am thinking on this problem several days and I have no solution. My task is to make it to be below 50 ms.

Given a sequence of numbers, calculate the longest possible sequence of jumps from each number.

- You can only jump on a number that is greater than the current one.
- You can jump on a number, only if there isn't one with a greater value between.
- You can jump only from left to right.

I have this solution:

```
static int[] fast(string inputNumbers)
{
    var numbers = inputNumbers.Trim().Split().Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
    var numN = numbers.Length;

    var jumpList = new int[numN];
    var initialJump = 0;
    int counter = 0, max = numbers.Max();

    for (int i = numN - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (i + 1 < numN && numbers[i] < numbers[i + 1])
        {
            jumpList[i] = jumpList[i + 1] + 1;
            continue;
        }

        initialJump = numbers[i];

        if (initialJump == max)
        {
            continue;
        }

        for (int j = i + 1; j < numN; j++)
        {
            if (initialJump == max)
            {
                break;
            }

            if (initialJump < numbers[j])
            {
                counter++;
                initialJump = numbers[j];
            }
        }

        jumpList[i] = counter;
        counter = 0;
    }

    return jumpList;
}
```

There is similar problem for Java here:
[Find longest possible sequence for jumps on next bigger number](/q/75361916/find-longest-possible-sequence-for-jumps-on-next-bigger-number)

I am writing the solution in C#.

Comment: What is your data set?   When I do this for 10,000 random generated numbers then I get well under 50ms.   BTW:   First thing to do is to accept your numbers as an array and not a string (or at least exclude this from your timing).  The conversation will take some time and skew your result, in my case it took 33% - 40% longer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have the inner loop, the time complexity of your algorithm is O(²). This can be done with O() time complexity.

The trick is to use a stack which will keep track of numbers in decreasing order as they are visited from the backwards iteration. Whenever a value is not less than the top of the stack, that top element is popped from the stack. The number of jumps for that value/index corresponds to the size of the stack, since the stack will have the values you can jump to.

Here is your code adapted with this stack feature:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

// ...

    static int[] fast(string inputNumbers)
    {
        var numbers = inputNumbers.Trim().Split().Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
        var jumpList = new int[numbers.Length];
        Stack<int> stack = new Stack<int>();
        for (int i = numbers.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            while (stack.Count > 0 &&  numbers[i] >= stack.Peek()) {
                stack.Pop();
            }
            jumpList[i] = stack.Count;
            stack.Push(numbers[i]);
        }

        return jumpList;
    }
```

As a value can only be pushed and popped once from the stack, the time complexity is O().